# PowerShell equivalent for cURL command uploading file

Tags: windows, post, powershell, curl, http-post

I am able to send HTTP POST a text file to my server using the following cURL command:

```
curl -i -F file=@file.txt http://www.website.com/put_file
```

The server is expecting a file from $_FILES['file'].

I have the following so far but it is not working:

```
$url = http://www.website.com/put_file
$file = "c:\file.txt"
$wc = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.UploadFile($url, $file.FullName)
```

it returns 0, and it did not upload to the server

How can I send the file as $_FILES['file']? Also, how can I see the response from the server?

Comment: I ended up downloading the curl executable for windows, and it worked wonders!

Answer (score 9):

I think it should be something like this:

```
$body = "file=$(get-content file.txt -raw)"
Invoke-RestMethod -uri http://www.websetite.com/put_file -method POST -body $body
```

Note: this does require PowerShell V3.  Also, you might need to specify the `-ContentType` parameter as `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`.  I recommend getting [Fiddler2](http://fiddler2.com/) and use it to inspect the request in both the curl and Inovke-RestMethod cases to help get the irm parameters correct.  This is assuming the file contents are fairly small and non-binary.  If not, you probably need to go to content type multipart/form-data.

Comment: curl's -F _is_ a multipart/form-data POST, so I guess most of this answer is then... not accurate

Answer (score 5):

In Powershell you can use curl.exe instead of curl (yes, are different commands: http://get-cmd.com/?p=5181)

```
curl.exe -i -F file=@file.txt http://www.website.com/put_file
```

Or you can use Invoke-RestMethod from powershell 3

More details about Invoke-RestMethod from powershell 3 at: https://superuser.com/questions/344927/powershell-equivalent-of-curl

Comment: This is not what the OP asked for.

Comment: Sorry @WarrenP , but he asked for 'PowerShell equivalent for cURL command', that's curl.exe and the included link point to the exact answer to that question and fixes his problem

Comment: The link you linked to provides an accepted answer of Invoke-RestMethod:

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, I download curl.exe for windows, and still used curl.

Comment: This sort of thing is better done as an edit to your question.

Answer (score -2):

After a couple hours of using fiddler to try to match curl, I gave up and just used this guy's function (See link below).  Worked like a charm.

http://blog.majcica.com/2016/01/13/powershell-tips-and-tricks-multipartform-data-requests/